# golang type interface returns nil value

Tags: go

Hello one of the processes will set the CustomerSalary and figure out the right way to obtain the value from the empty interfaces

```
type Customer struct {
    CustomerSalary interface{}
}
```

```
log.Println("Here---")
log.Println(customer.CustomerSalary)
salary, ok := customer.CustomerSalary.(string)
log.Println("salary***=", salary)
```

When the program is run it returns nil value to it but has the value for e.g `1332`

**Output**

```
Here---
1332
salary***=
```

Even I have tried

```golang
_, ok := customer.CustomerSalary.(float64)
    log.Println("floay64 = " , ok )
    _, ok = customer.CustomerSalary.(string)
    log.Println("string = " , ok )
    _, ok = customer.CustomerSalary.(int64)
    log.Println("int64 = " , ok )
```

The result appears to be false

```
floay64 =  false
string =  false
int64 =  false
```

**Updated to Cerise Limón comment**

`fmt.Printf("type is %T\n", customer.CustomerSalary`

## Output

`type is json.Number`

Comment: take a look at the package's documentation: [`json.Number`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.6#Number), there you can see all of its three methods, and you can use those methods to get the value in the type you want.

Answer (score -2):

I can get the result successfully

```
Hello, 世界
Here---
10000
salary***= 10000
```

Please try here https://go.dev/play/p/NGaLHqf3lKm